# How to combine scanner input and enum for months of the year?

Tags: java, date, enums, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to play around with a program I made to tell you what your zodiac sign is and previously I was just running scannner inuput through if statements to determine the sign given birth month and birth day. Now my mentor has challenged me to use enum and switching between months of the year. My problem is conceptually I'm very confused as to how to bring these two concepts together

Here's my code below so far but I'm really just shooting in the dark here

```
import java.util.Scanner;

enum Month {
    
January,
February,
March,
April,
May,
June,
July,
August,
September,
October,
November,
December
}

class MyStarSign3 {

    Month month;

    public EnumTest(Month month) {

        this.month = month;
    }

    public void monthBorn() {
        switch (month) {

            case January:


            case February:


            case March:


            case April:


            case May:


            case June: 


            case July:


            case August:


            case September:


            case October:


            case November:


            case December:


            default:


                
        }
    }


                public static void main(String[] args) {

                        Scanner monthInput = new Scanner(System.in);

                        String birthMonth = monthInput.nextLine();

                }

}
```

Comment: Using enums is a good idea. You need not create your own `Month` enum, it is built in already, and it’s better not to "reinvent the wheel". Inport `java.time.Month`. You may consider an enum for the astrological signs too. Inside each of the cases of your switch statement you will still need if-else for choosing between the two possible Zodiac sings for that month.

Comment: It may not be what your mentor intended, but for production code one would use a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH)` and convert into a `Month` enum value using `Month.from(yourDateTimeFormatter.parse(userInputString))`.

Comment: I think what I'm confused on is how I implement this with my scanner input, I'm not sure If the way I've constructed the program makes it out of scope or not

Comment: I had intended `userInputString` to be the string read from the user through your scanner -- what is caled  `birthMonth` in your code, yes, sorry, using a different name was confusing.

Comment: Thank you. I think another issue I'm having Is I'm not sure if these methods should be in the main method or outside of it. When It's outside the main method I'm struggling to understand what's actually supposed to be in my main method. This challenge is really exposing what I do and don't know lol

Comment: I understand. It’s a design decision what to put where, so there isn’t just one correct answer. Options include: (1) Put it in the `main` method and pass the `Month` object obtained as argument to the method you are calling. (2) Pass the string from the user to the method and convert to `Month` inside the method. (3) Code a separate method for reading the user input and converting it. This method would then return a `Month` object after having read the input through the scanner and converted.

Comment: also I'm having a problem where im trying to switch for each case, but i keep getting "January cannot be resolved to a variable" when trying to pass in the user input for each case. I'm using switch(Month.valueOf(birthMonth)) and I'm unsure why this doesn't work

Comment: If you are using the built-in `Month` enum, the constants are named `JANUARY`, etc., in all uppercase (this follows the Java naming conventions). So you need `switch (Month.valueOf(birthMonth.toUpperCase()))` and then `case Month.JANUARY:`,, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `valueOf` method on the `enum` type to convert a `String` to the corresponding enum.

```java
switch (Month.valueOf(birthMonth)) {
case January -> System.out.println("January"); // or do something else...
// etc...
}
```

You might also want to catch `IllegalArgumentException` in case the user enters an invalid month.

Comment: Thank you friend you just put together the two concepts I've been reading about all night

Comment: though when I do use the valueOf method to convert a string to the corresponding enum, it seems like that is causing an issue where my months are now in white text on VSC and I'm not exactly sure why

Comment: Not knowing Visual Studio Code that doesn’t necessarily sound like a bad sign to me.